# CSS display issue in chrome

Tags: css

i have a menu that has the following css:-

```
#top-navigation {
padding: 45px 0 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 200;
float: right;
}
```

Now i have a notification that is displayed over the top of this menu with the css:-

```
    .SmallBox {
    position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 20px;
padding-right: 30px;
width: 420px;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

the problem is that due to the relative attribute of menu it is giving me problems and the notification box does not totally display over the menu in chrome.

Comment: can you share the fiddle with us

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: i have bought a notifications plugin and wont be able to do that.

Comment: to fix the css, we have to have a little of the html to figure out whats going on.

Comment: So either your plug in is server side, in which you can share the HTML that it produces, or the plug in is client side, in which you can link to it from a public server.  That would be an odd license for the plug in that was client-side, and you aren't allowed to send it to clients.

Comment: u want additional css? i can give that. what else do you want?

Comment: If do not know what is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net just follow the link and make there a neutral example of your menu that shows the bug :) (html+css + js if you use it )